# Ubuntu 22.04 wont boot after disk clone

Tags: boot, 22.04, hard-drive, dd, clone

I am attempting to migrate my OS boot disk from a 512GB to a 1TB drive.   I booted off a live USB and used dd to clone the orignal drive to the new drive. Then I shut it down and unplugged the old drive and plugged the new one into the same sata slot. I thought it was working because it was booting and I even saw the Ubuntu log with the loading symbol.  After a bit it changed to a CLI screen with a bunch of messages I don't understand and now its stuck on that screen.  I get a lot of messages "Array-index-out-of-bounds". [The screen I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w4eO.jpg)
The weird thing is I can remote in through teamviewer to this screen. So some portion of the OS is booting, but it is still failing to fully run.

Comment: The UUIDs may have gotten out of sync. Run `lsblk`, and make sure each UUID that appear in `/etc/fstab` matches one of them

Comment: When you boot, do you get to a terminal? Or a grub> prompt?

Comment: @darth_epoxy It doesn't give me a grub prompt or a terminal.  I can type on the screen I posted above but hitting enter just gives me a new line and doesn't give any response, regardless of the command.

Comment: @DanielT I'll try booting off the original drive.   That one never saw the new drive before I cloned it.  So the cloned fstab wouldn't have the new drives UUID.

Comment: Connecting a cloned drive and the original drive to the same computer may confuse it